# how to not reload when loading ajax modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am putting a modal alert on the screen when a user clicks a choice of a dropdown like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#id_state').change(function(e){
        var selection = $("#id_state").val();
        if(selection == 1){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var entryType = 'diabetes';
            var data = new Object();
            data.entryType = entryType;
            programAlertModal(programAlertModalCallback, data); 

            return false; 

        }
     });

     $('#id_state').trigger('change');
});
```

Program alert modal is then called here:

```
programAlertModal:function(callback, data){
            var entryType = data.entryType;
            var url = '/shared/enrollment/'+entryType+'/';

            $.get(url, function(result) {  
                callback(result, entryType); 

                return false;
            });
        },

        programAlertModalCallback:function(result, entryType){  
            $( "body" ).append(result);

        },
```

The result is some html that looks like this:

```
<div class="takeover">
  <div class="takeover-bg"></div>
  <div class="takeover-body">
  {% if entry_type == 'diabetes' %}
    <h1>My awesome title</h1>

    <a href="">Dismiss</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I dismiss what is loaded without reloading the page (and clearing the dropdown selection)?

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: can you post the fiddle?

Comment: @VitorLuis I posted more code.  Do you need the css too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the Dismiss link so we can reference it:

```
<a href="#" class="dismiss">Dismiss</a>
```

Then bind a handler that removes the modal in the callback:

```
programAlertModalCallback: function(result, entryType) {
  var $result = $(result).appendTo("body");
  $result.find("a.dismiss").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $result.remove();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an `e` parameter to your function and add `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the default behaviour of the `a` tag that reloads the page. You should also  include `href="#"` in your `a` since leaving it blank causes some trouble in some cases.